# php pass function reference to another function to be executed on return

Tags: php, oop, function-pointers

in this example; if i call wash_hands then it will first execute `$this->eat()` then `$this->log()`.

but what i really want is that `$this->log` to be executed first then `$this->eat()`

```
function log($msg,$return=null){
//..do some logic

return $return;
}

function eat(){
//...start eating
}

function wash_hands(){
//...wash hands
return $this->log('hand washed',$this->eat());
}
```

is there a way to do it and it still would work even if ..

log() function is in another class

eat() is a private/protected methode of same class as wash_hands ?

Comment: How can you call `log` first if `log` is using the result of eat as an argument If `log` doesn't need the argument why not just call log then return the results of `eat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed, `$this->eat()` calls the method immediately. Unfortunateley `$this->eat` is not a reference to the function because the syntax would be the same for a property `$eat`. But you can have callable variables that reference to methods in the form `array($object, $method)`:

```
$this->log('hand washed', array($this, 'eat'));
```

which can be used like that:

```
function log($msg,$return=null) {
    // ...
    // now calling the passed method
    if (is_callable($return)) {
        return $return();
    }
}
```

**But:**

> is there a way to do it and it still would work even if ..
>
> log() function is in another class
>
> eat() is a private/protected methode of same class as wash_hands ?

that's not possible without exposing the private function in one way or another.

**Update:**

With [Closure binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) in PHP 5.4 you actually can pass the private function:

```
$callback = function() { return $this->eat(); }
$this->log('hand washed', $callback->bindTo($this));
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want can be obtained by simply calling the method afterwards:

```
function wash_hands(){
    //...wash hands
    $this->log('hand washed');
    return $this->eat();
}
```